# 64-bit Windows API struct alignment caused Access Denied error on named pipe

Tags: c++, winapi, struct

It has taken me two days, but I've finally narrowed down the source of an `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (5) error when attempting to `CallNamedPipe` as a problem with structure alignment. We had a 32-bit service and a 32-bit application, and I am trying to update the service to be a 64-bit service. The strange thing is that everything was working fine in 32-bit mode, but in 64-bit mode `CallNamedPipe` from the 32-bit application was reporting an access denied error.

The service was already setting up a `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` structure and populating the `lpSecurityDescriptor` member with a properly initialized `PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`. And this wasn't reporting any errors when passed to `CreateNamedPipe`. I still don't know why it wasn't reporting an error; maybe bad security attributes silently falls back to a default instead of failing.

Through many gyrations (including some earlier incomplete/incorrect attempts at changing structure alignment - debugging service startup code is not easy), I came to realize that the project setting that sets the default struct alignment to 1 byte (/Zp1) was causing problems. When I finally used `#pragma pack(push,8)` before all occurrences of `#include <windows.h>` and `#pragma pack(pop)` afterward, then things started working.

My question now is why is this necessary. I see that there are many header files in the Windows API that explicitly set structure alignment by including `pshpack1.h`, `pshpack2.h`, `pshpack4.h`, `pshpack8.h` and `poppack.h`. How am I to know when the Windows API controls its own packing and when it becomes my responsibility to have the proper pack level set? Shouldn't every Windows API declaration that cares about structure alignment set the proper packing so I don't have to sift through all the code in the system for anything including Windows API header files? One alternative would be to change the project setting to use default structure alignment, but I have to assume that this was done because we have even more code in our system relying on 1-byte structure alignment than we have relying on the Windows API.

This is what the server side code looks like:

```
BOOL OpenMyPipe()
{
   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
   PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD;

   printf("sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) == %d\n", sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
   pSD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)GlobalAlloc(LPTR, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
   if (pSD == NULL)
      return FALSE;

   if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(pSD, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
      return FALSE;

   if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSD, TRUE, (PACL)NULL, FALSE))
      return FALSE;

   sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
   sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = pSD;
   sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

   char szPipeName[MAX_PATH];
   sprintf(szPipeName, "\\\\.\\pipe\\%s%s", "__SQLTST_",
      "MAINMR");

   hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(szPipeName, PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
      PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,
      1, 0, 0, NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER, &sa);

   if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      return FALSE;
   return TRUE;
}
```

For simplicity's sake I verified this with a small VB.NET client:

```
Sub Main()
  Dim pipes = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("\\.\pipe\")

  Using pipe As New System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream(".", "__SQLTST_MAINMR")
     Dim message(16) As Byte
     pipe.Connect(3000)
     Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id), message, 4)
     pipe.Write(message, 0, 16)
  End Using
End Sub
```

I believe the error only occurs when the server side code is running under a different account like the SYSTEM account. I don't know how to easily test that, though. What I do know is that the above code will *not* fail even with no `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` set up when it's all running under the same account as regular application code. Also, of course, you have to set the structure alignment in the server code to 1 byte to see the error.

Comment: Part of my question is whether this **is** a bug in Win API, or whether I am missing some huge assumption that will impact potentially hundreds of API calls throughout the whole system.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not what you think it is.  I do wonder why you are packing structs though. Why do you want to mis-align your data?

Comment: I don't know. I inherited this code from a system of more than 2 million lines. I can only assume that it's because we have many structures stored in files from 15+ years ago that need to be aligned the way they were long ago. I'm reasonably certain that the above could would reproduce the error if I knew how to run the server code under the SYSTEM account easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows SDK expects packing to be 8 bytes.  From [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Projects should be compiled to use the default structure packing, which is currently 8 bytes because the largest integral type is 8 bytes. Doing so ensures that all structure types within the header files are compiled into the application with the same alignment the Windows API expects. It also ensures that structures with 8-byte values are properly aligned and will not cause alignment faults on processors that enforce data alignment.

This is necessary to ensure that data structures are aligned as the system expects.  I suspect the reason for not doing it explicitly is that they want the default, so [why ask for anything else](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/27/6873648.aspx).  Changing the packing is relatively rare and should be confined to specific circumstances.  If Microsoft added in `#pragma pack(push,8)` to every header file, they would be implicitly saying it is normal to change alignment.

Unaligned structures save space, but reduce performance as [alignment faults](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are generated when accessing unaligned members.

The Windows SDK does change alignments for structures for a number of reasons.  One might be for file formats that need to read either 32 or 64-bit data structures.  For example, the PE-file format can be read using either `IMAGE_THUNK_DATA64` or `IMAGE_THUNK_DATA32`.  The former needs 8 byte padding whilst the latter needs 4 byte padding.  Similarly, `Wininet.h` will pack the data structures differently depending on whether it is being compiled for 32-bit or 64-bit code.  These are legitimate changes in packing, but with a specific reason.

Comment: That makes me wonder why there are more than 80 occurrences of including pshpack8.h in the Windows 8.1 SDK include files directory.

Comment: I've added a bit more info about why `pshpack8.h` is used in the header files.  There are many legitimate uses.  The `/Zp` flag exists to set the packing to whatever you want.  Not every program has to use the Windows SDK.